# Control.Style.Add not working in asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, css, asp.net

My page looks like this:

```
<asp:Panel ID="UpdateProgress" ClientIdMode="Static" runat="server">                
</asp:Panel>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server">
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Basically, I am using the UpdateProgress div (which has fixed position and high z-index) instead of an UpdateProgress control (since the latter wasn't working the way I wanted it to).

On a client button click I run this JS:

```
function displayLoading() {
            document.getElementById("UpdateProgress").style.display = "block";
        }
```

then I run this event handler in the code behind (I have already verified that they execute in this order):

```
public void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   ...do stuff
   UpdateProgress.Style.Add("display", "none");
}
```

The idea is that when I finish doing the server side logic, I can let the user interact with the screen again. However, the UpdateProgress div does not get hidden.

Comment: Perhaps you're missing a check for PostBack in Page load event? Seems like your controls are just getting redrawn.

Comment: It is in an update panel. Also, the div starts off (due to css) as display: none

Comment: I am not initiating my ajax requests... The update panel is.

Comment: @Byc You could call a JavaScript from the Code behind when the blick button has been finished.

Comment: @Wilfredo P Yeah, that was going to be my last resort =/

Comment: @Byc that is not pretty good, but I think that you dont have other way :/

Comment: Have you tried calling UpdatePanel.Update(); to force it to update all child controls? Just as an FYI, have a look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.updatepanel.updatemode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

You can change UpdateMode to `Always` or manually call the `Update` method on UpdatePanel control.

Comment: Add this UpdatePanel1.update() at the botton on the Button1Click?

Comment: None of this is working. Really frustrating. =/. Calling Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "hideLoading", "hideLoading()", true); from code behind does not work either.

Comment: make sure you display style you're trying to create isn't getting overwritten somewhere else. test it with `UpdateProgress.Style.Add("display", "none !important");` Also put  a breakpoint there to make sure that code is being run, since you dont show the other code in the method there could be a try block stopping an error and you wouldn't know better.